# why storm performance are getting very slow after few minutes?

Tags: cloud, bigdata, apache-storm

I'm running throughput topology for testing the performance.
In the first two minutes I'm getting good performance average of 450k emitted/sec
after 10 minutes it goes down to average of 100k per/sec.

What could be the cause?

throughput test: 
https://github.com/stormprocessor/storm-benchmark/blob/master/src/jvm/storm/benchmark/ThroughputTest.java

Comment: This is really a question for your profiler.

Comment: why did you set the ackers to 0?

Comment: Is it running into long/frequent GC pauses after creating lots of random strings?

Comment: Read @DonBranson's comment repeatedly

Comment: Okay, that's hilarious. :)

Comment: @DonBranson is right, i overcome this issue by increasing `-Xmx` value in `worker.childopts`.

Answer (score 0):

There can be several reasons which are possible:
1. Check if your Heap requirement is met and the same is provided to the worker JVM.
Via Linux top command/GC logs you can verify the same.
In case you want to increase it use the XMX parameters.
Parameters :

```
-XmsAg -XmxAg -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:-PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Xloggc:/tmp/gc.log
```

2. Huge major GC cycles 
   Major GC cycles take a lot of time and cause application pauses for a large heap.
   Read this blog to optimize the same :
   https://engineering.linkedin.com/garbage-collection/garbage-collection-optimization-high-throughput-and-low-latency-java-applications
3. A zombie arraylist/hashmap clogging your code - use profiler like jVisualVM or Yourkit to point this issue out if unable to do via code review.

Check Storm UI to find out non-performant bolts and tweak them accordingly.
Also, prefer CMS GC with tuning parameters as per your requirement.
G1 garbage collector will give you speedy collection cycles with minimal application stopped time but will show up a blown up process memory as compared to CMS.
Prefer G1, in-case you don't mind the larger process size(much large as compared to heap size).